# how to split a text in to paragraph with a particular string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long text file ... I read the text file and store the content in a string...
Now I want this text to split. The below is an image which shows what I want.
In the image "***This is common text***" means this string is common in every paragraph.

[image]

Green squares shows that I want that part in string array.
but how o do that... I have tried Regular expression for this... but isn't working....
please help

Comment: Could you put your attempt in the question?

Comment: (This is a common text\s*[^This is a common text].*?)\s*(This is a common text)

Comment: This is not nearly enough information for us to guess the structure of the text you're trying to match. Please explain how exactly to determine where a match starts, what it may contain, what it must not contain, and where it ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `RegEx.Split()` using this pattern:

```
(.*This is common text.*)
```

Well, giving `priority to RegEx` over the `string functions` is always leads to a performance overhead.

It would be great if you use: (**UnTested** but it will give you an idea)

```
string[] lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("FilePath")
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
List<string> lstgroup = new List<string>();

int i=0;
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    if(line.Tolower().contains("this is common text"))
    {
         if(i > 0)
         {
             lst.AddRange(lstgroup.ToArray());

             // Print elements here
             lstgroup.Clear();
         }
         else { i++; }
         continue;
    }
    else
    {
      lstgroup.Add(line)
    }
}
i = 0;
// Print elements here too
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to split on but you could use

```
string[] stringArray = Regex.Split(yourString, regex);
```

If you want a more concrete example you will have to (as others mentioned) give us more information regardning what the text looks like rather than just "common text".

Comment: As I said then I/we need more than "common text". So we know what to split on.